# Is there a website that provides code for the Like, Tweet, +1 and Share buttons?

Tags: social-networking, facebook-like, google-plus-one

I've found a [Wordpress plugin](http://letusbuzz.com/tweet-share-like-plusone/) which provides code for all these buttons but I want to put them on my website (which doesn't run Wordpress).

Is there somewhere which provides the code or do I have to do them all separately?

I'm trying to add them to this website: [Compress My Code](http://compressmycode.com/).

Comment: last line looks like an ad ...

Comment: It's there to put the question in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this](http://sharethis.com/) which seems to have everything I need, thanks for the other answer too though :)

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of plug-ins for that available out there if you care to search.
My personal preference is the "SexyBookmarks" which look a bit like this:
[image]

And [here's](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/integrate-sexybookmarks-html-page-javascript/) how you add them.